# What is known about the "forbidden 7"?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

In Super Smash Bros Brawl, there are 7 characters that have "files" found in the game, but do not make an appearance in the actual game. What I want to know is in what state were these characters and what else do we know about them? (Were there models in the game, movesets, are they in any form playable? etc etc)

Comment: Here's a link to what I'm talking about http://super-smash-bros.wikia.com/wiki/Unfinished_Code  Nothing I find gives satisfactory information on the characters though....

Comment: Hello, Jeff - Site policy discourages questions on both unreleased content and on questions related to the developer's intent, both because there is no real way to provide an objective, authoritative answer. Short of hacking the Wii / ISO and looking through the code yourself, there is no way anyone could answer this question.